# Macro to Copy Content from Excel and paste in MS Word

Tags: vba

I have an idea for a report generation macro from Excel to Word.

The report format in excel is as below .

[image: Mock screen of report format in excel]

The report in word

[image]

There is an existing code as below to copy and paste in word . But is there a way to format it as in the above screenshot?

```
Sub TestingMacAndWin()
Dim appWD As Object
Dim wddoc As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set appWD = GetObject(, "Word.application")    'gives error 429 if Word is not open
If Err = 429 Then
    Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.application")    'creates a Word application
    Err.Clear
End If

Set wddoc = appWD.Documents.Add
appWD.Visible = True

With appWD.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .TopMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .BottomMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .LeftMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .RightMargin = appWD.InchesToPoints(0.3)
End With

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D2").CopyPicture xlScreen
appWD.Selection.Paste

appWD.Activate

End Sub
```

source : http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac030.htm

Answer (score 1):

Paste your data in. Stop your Macro (`stop` command will do that), then record your formatting (**Alt + T, M, R**). Go get the recorded macro, and paste it into your macro, fixing the object you are working on (eg `.ActiveDocument` to `AppWD.ActiveDocument` though you probably don't have to do).

COM have changed over the years, and is now recommended to `GetObject` the `Document` object, not the `Application` Object. Among other minor things it elininates *reference counting* problems on the `Application` object, this where the application doen't exit when closed.